# Update resource from external API android

Tags: android

In my app I want to update the strings.xml file at runtime. So the idea is to download the content from an external API and then update the strings.xml file. Does anybody had any past working experience on this or any idea how to achieve this goal will be a great help!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify resources at runtime. You are welcome to ship a new APK that contains the new resources, though.

You are also welcome to download files from the Internet, parse them, and use their contents. However, you have no means of using them literally as string resources. They will just be strings (or whatever else you parse from the file).

Comment: Ok. So there is no way to dynamically update/modify the strings.xml file? Actually I am not too much interested to go with saving the internal local files and than fetching the data from it. @CommonsWare

Comment: @AmarpreetSInghJohal: "So there is no way to dynamically update/modify the strings.xml file?" -- correct. As I wrote, you cannot modify resources at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. If you ever happen to add values to the strings.xml at runtime, their ids won't be generated in the R.class, you can alternatively save those strings to another file on the phone (database file, json file, xml, etc.).